# NoVNC being blocked behind firewall, how can I find the port being blocked?

Tags: firewall, vnc, openstack

We have an OpenStack cloud running internally and wanted to allow student's access to the NoVNC console from within Openstack's Horizon web panel.

Everything work's internally however after adding port 80,443 and 6080 (The port novnc listens on) on our Fortigate firewall The NoVNC console just times out. When I allow ALL TCP ports on the Fortigate I can access the VNC console.

I've tried looking at netstat which shows my connection to the VNC console when all ports are open. However i've not had any luck at finding which port is being blocked.

```
tcp        0     31 10.0.79.2:6080          217.169.0.245:64478     ESTABLISHED 110        298904      27769/python
```

How can I find which port is blocking NoVNC?

Comment: Did you try opening up `5090` as well?

Comment: Just added it to the firewall, no luck unfortunately. Running an nmap scan now see it that reveals anything.